# LocalFingerprints: cannot compute fingerprint

Tags: android

I am getting one strange error it occurs randomly to any time and crashes the app. i am testing on nexus 6 in Android 7.0

here is log cat

> E/LocalFingerprints: cannot compute fingerprint for: content://media/external/images/media/306155
>                                                         java.io.IOException: read failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
>                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:481)
>                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:252)
>                                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.read(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:889)
>                                                             at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
>                                                             at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
>                                                             at java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:161)
>                                                             at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
>                                                             at kei.b(PG:81)
>                                                             at imp.a(PG:1324)
>                                                             at ilf.a(PG:131)
>                                                             at com.google.android.libraries.social.autobackup.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:81)
>                                                             at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>                                                          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
>                                                             at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
>                                                             at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:169)
>                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:231)
>                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:471)
>                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:252) 
>                                                             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.read(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:889) 
>                                                             at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273) 
>                                                             at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) 
>                                                             at java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:161) 
>                                                             at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) 
>                                                             at kei.b(PG:81) 
>                                                             at imp.a(PG:1324) 
>                                                             at ilf.a(PG:131) 
>                                                             at com.google.android.libraries.social.autobackup.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:81) 
>                                                             at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67) 
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: is your application do something with fingerprint? Because from first look its look like device try to backup fingerprint from device & that is not available.

Comment: nope nothing related to fingerprint

Comment: @nikhil that's why I am totally confused

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on an LG G6.